# The dependencies between opencv libraries

Tags: c++, opencv

When we build the opencv library, either in a dynamic way or in a static way, we will produce several separated libraries. Take the 2.48 version for example, we will have

```
opencv_core248 opencv_imgproc248 zlib  IlmImf comctl32  opencv_highgui248 libpng
```

and so on. So my question here is clearly there are some dependencies between these libraries, for example, if I want to invoke `opencv_core248` and `opencv_imgproc24` library in a project, I have link errors. Then, if I add `zlib` library, the compilation error will be solved.

**Question:** I want to ask a very general question: how can I know the dependencies between all the libraries insider opencv? Are there some documents I can follow? Thanks.

Comment: Clearly you mean linking error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a document listing all the dependencies between the OpenCV libraries.

However I can suggest two methods to find out these dependencies:

- Using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), a free tool allowing to analyze executables and DLLs. For instance, if you open `opencv_calib3dXXX.DLL` (where `XXX` represents your OpenCV version), you'll see that it requires `opencv_coreXXX.dll`,  `opencv_flannXXX.dll`,  `opencv_imgprocXXX.dll` and  `opencv_features2dXXX.dll` and some system DLLs.
- Using the project structure generated by [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), a free tool for cross-platform compilation which is used for compliing OpenCV from sources. For instance, if I generate the project structure for VS2010 and open it, I can right-click on the project associated to `opencv_calib3d` and view the project dependencies.

I mentionned the tools I know and use for Windows, but equivalent tools must also exist for other platforms.